# How should way·yō·mer be translated into English?

Tags: genesis, hebrew

way·yō·mer is translated in Genesis 1 as "And God said" or "Then God said". I was hoping someone would have some insight as to which is correct. Is there a future tense ("then") implied in the word or is it just something additional ("and") God said that may have been in the future or past? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center's](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) sections on both asking and answering questions.

Answer (score 2):

The initial *waw* (וַ) in וַיֹּ֥אמֶר is just the conjunction (e.g., "and" or "then" for stylistic reasons). The verb itself is in the Qal (from אמר) and is third masculine singular ("he said"). This construction is what scholars refer to as the Qal narrative tense (which is the most common use of the preterite in biblical Hebrew). "The narrative verb indicates *sequential action in past time*" (i.e., past-tense narration).<sup>1</sup> The Qal narrative is sometimes confused with the imperfect, but "the narrative has a *pataḥ* or *qameṣ* and the doubling of the letter following the *waw*, whereas a *waw* + imperfect has a *shewa* and no doubling of the following letter."<sup>2</sup> Making it slightly trickier to parse, "אָמַר shows a slightly different vowel pattern (a *ḥolem* in the first syllable) in both the imperfect and narrative forms because the first radical is an *aleph*."<sup>3</sup>

So it's just a standard (and common) past-tense narration: "and he said."

Using other English conjunctions to translate the conjunction (*waw*) is fine and for stylistic reasons helps break up the monotony of reading narratives where almost every sentence might otherwise begin with "and." It has nothing to do with future tense (future would be something like "he will say," regardless of the conjunction used).

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> William Fullilove, Introduction to Hebrew: A Guide for Learning and Using Biblical Hebrew (Phillipsburg, NJ: P&R Publishing, 2017), 145.</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> *Ibid.,* 146.</sub>

<sub><sup>3</sup> *Ibid.,* 146–7.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for that answer. Does this mean that the "and" MUST mean sequential action in past time, or can it also simply mean "another" without indicating a time sequence? Thank you!

Comment: It's a conjunction. It has no direct relationship with time (i.e., *tense* and in some instances, *aspect,* which are derived from the *verb*). A conjunction's job is to join together sentences. That's it. Any inference of time is not inherent to the conjunction itself. Just like "and" in English. "Then" is ambiguous as to past or future, but is a feature of *English* and the translator's choice of how to best show a sequence of events in narrative accounts. The Hebrew is simply a conjunction, and its role is to connect two words, sentences, or phrases together.

Comment: The verb for "speak" itself implies past tense ("he said"), which has little to nothing to do with the conjunction. If you're trying to build some kind of theological argument on whether these actions took place sequentially or not, you're moving beyond linguistics into other [modes of discourse](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/886/423) (which is fine, but that's a different question than the one you asked).

Comment: Keep in mind that for "time" to be a factor on earth/land, you'd have to have some celestial bodies (e.g., the sun) before it even begins to become a factor in the sense we think of time today, which doesn't even exist until day 4 of the creation. But this is going beyond linguistics....

Comment: (but to be clear, a narrative implies a sequence of events, but in respect to the *verb,* not the *conjunction*)